# Share google analytics campaign with another gmail account

Tags: google-analytics

My friend put a backlink of my site(A.com) in his website(b.com)
I can see the input traffic of this backlink from my Google Analytics in

**Acquisition -> campaigns -> All campaign ->**

I want to share the data with him so that he can track how many of people have came from his website to mine.
How can I do that?
I don't want to just send him the PDF of excel report. I want it to be real time.

But I also only want him to see the data of this campaign and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) he could set up an tag which was triggered anytime someone clicked on his outbound links to your website and have that logged as an event in his Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Google Data Studio report with the Analytics data i.e charts/Numbers you want to share with him/her and share that file.

The file is updated in real-time.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Need Help creating or sharing the Data Studio report. Refer: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7459147?hl=en

Comment: If problem still persists, let me know. We'll figure out another way.